# How to integrate JMX into tomcat app or what I doing wrong?

Tags: jmx, spring-jmx

I tried to configure JMX with no luck.. What I did?

1. Created class:

   ```
   public class JmxTestBean implements IJmxTestBean {

       private String name;
       private int age;
       private boolean isSuperman;

       public int getAge() {
           return age;
       }

       public void setAge(int age) {
           this.age = age;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
       }

       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       public int add(int x, int y) {
           return x + y;
       }

       public void dontExposeMe() {
           throw new RuntimeException();
       }
   }
   ```
2. And after that I've added to spring config following lines:

   ```
   <bean id="mbeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean"/>

   <bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
       <property name="beans">
           <map>
               <entry key="bean:name=testBean1" value-ref="testBean"/>
           </map>
       </property>
       <property name="server" ref="mbeanServer"/>
   </bean>    
   <bean id="testBean" class="com.db.gbs.jmx.simulator.JmxTestBean">
       <property name="name" value="TEST"/>
       <property name="age" value="100"/>
   </bean>
   ```
3. As last step I tried to setup env variable as following:

   ```
   set CATALONA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010"
   ```

   And started tomcat7:

   ```
   mvn jetty:run-exploded -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize=100000000
   ```

   Using JConsole tried to connect and got following error:

   ```
   Could not connect to localhost:9010 : Failed to retrieve 
   RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException 
   [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection 
   refused to host: localhost; nested exception is:         
   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
   Could not connect to localhost:9010. Make sure the JVM 
   is running and that you are using the correct protocol 
   in the Service URL service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9010/jmxrmi).
   ```

What I doing wrong?